# I can´t get all the data while Web Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to web scrape this URL = https://www.ventanillaunicaenfermeria.es/BuscarColegiados.php.
I need to gather the values of "N°cole." column and "Nombre Colegiado" column.

I'm using BeautifulSoup but I get only values of "N°cole." column. How can I fix that?

Thanks!

This is my code:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

page = requests.get('https://www.ventanillaunicaenfermeria.es/BuscarColegiados.php')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all("span",{'class':'colColegiado'})
numero_col = []
for i in data:
    data_num = i.text.strip()
    numero_col.append(data_num)
numero_col
['Nº cole.',
 '6478',
 '13107',
 '7341',
 '12110',
 '5625',
 '4877',
 '4700',
 '9126',
 '8444',
 '13120',
 '5023',
 '12235',
 '7747',
 '17701',
 '17391',
 '17944',
 '17772',
 '7230',
 '11729',
 '17275']
```

Comment: "*I'm using BeautifulSoup but I get only values of "N°cole." column. How can I fix that?*" Well, I'd imagine the same way you extracted the values from the "N°cole." column - find the selectors and process them using the BeautifulSoup bindings. Stack Overflow isn't here to write your code for you - show us at least an attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Make sure to change `from requests import get` to `import requests` or change `requests.get` to `get`.

Answer (score -1):

You're currently fetching the values from the wrong html elements - it should be from all `<p>`s with the `resalto` class.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np

page = requests.get('https://www.ventanillaunicaenfermeria.es/BuscarColegiados.php')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all("p",{'class':'resalto'})
schools = []
for result in data:
    data_num = result.contents[0].text.strip()
    #numero_col.append(data_num)
    data_name = str(result.contents[1])
    schools.append((data_num,data_name))
print(schools)
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of selecting all `p` at once, you can loop through the paragraphs in the table only. The following code takes page number and saves the table to a csv file.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

pageno = 1
res = requests.get(f'https://www.ventanillaunicaenfermeria.es/BuscarColegiados.php?nombre=&ap=&colegio=&col=&nif=&pagina={pageno}')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
header = soup.find("div", {"id":"contactaForm"}).find("h4")
cols = [header.find("span").get_text(), header.get_text().replace(header.find("span").get_text(),"")]
data = []

for p in soup.find("div", {"id":"contactaForm"}).find_all("p"):
    if len(p['class']) == 0 or p['class'][0] == "resalto":
        child = list(p.children)
        data.append([child[0].get_text(strip=True), child[1]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Nº cole.               Nombre colegiado
0      6478             GUADALUPE  LAZARO LAZARO
1     13107             JOSE MARIA  PIÑA MANZANO
2      7341             HEIKE ELFRIEDE  BIRKHOLZ
3     12110                 ESTHER  TIZON ROLDAN
4      5625  MARIA DOLORES  TOMAS GARCIA-VAQUERO
5      4877         MARIA CARMEN  CASADO LLAVONA
6      4700   MANUEL  GUILABERT ORTEGA-VILLAIZAN
7      9126     MARIA ESPERANZA  ASENSIO ALMAZAN
8      8444        CONCEPCION  VIALARD RODRIGUEZ
9     13120           NURIA  VILLAESCUSA SANCHEZ
10     5023                 ARTURO  BONET BLANCO
11    12235               ALFONSO  JIMENEZ LOPEZ
12     7747              JACOBUS PETRUS  SINNIGE
13    17701                ANIA  BRAVO FIGUEREDO
14    17391                   LUSINE  DAMIRCHYAN
15    17944                 ISALKOU  DJIL MERHBA
16    17772       CARLA DENISSE  FIGUEROA PIEDRA
17     7230         MARIA ISABEL  VISO CABAÑERO
18    11729                PILAR  GARCIA SALAZAR
19    17275         MARIA  LOURDES  MALLEN LLUIS
```